# nginx vhost location parameters

Tags: php, nginx, virtualhost

I just transfered a website to a new server; here is my sites conf (vhost) in nginx and the last 2 entries from error.log .

The images are not displaying when the index.php loads.

regars,

---

server {

```
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4
    listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    server_name  maissane;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

    root   /var/www/alex.site.com;
    location / {
            index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9090;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

}

____________log errors:

2013/03/02 16:01:51 [error] 16637#0: *35 open() "/var/www/alex.site.com/images/right_<" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 65.94.70.3, server: alex, request: "GET /images/right_%3C?=%20$theme;%20?%3E.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "alex.site.com", referrer: "http://alex.site.com/index.php?p=bio"

2013/03/02 16:01:51 [error] 16637#0: *35 open() "/var/www/alex.site.com/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 65.94.70.3, server: alex, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "alex.site.com"

Comment: I get lots of errors in error.log:

Answer (score 1):

The log entry makes it pretty obvious.

You don't actually have a file `/images/right<?= $theme; =?>.jpg`.

Try providing a filename that exists.

Comment: There's a substitution that works on my other server. right_'ThemeName'.jpg       Why wouldn't it substitute anymore properly?

Comment: Who knows? Your question doesn't even address that issue. Perhaps you should look into it?

Answer (score 0):

As it seems the issue is in PHP config rather than nginx. <strike>Check your *php.ini* config for `short_open_tag` directive - it should be *On*, like</strike>

```
short_open_tag=On
```

or change the code to `/images/right_<?php echo $theme; ?>.jpg`.

#### Edit

As people point out, the usage of php short tags is **not recommended** for various reasons, one of  which you are now experiencing(new server doesn't support them by default). See [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use) for more info..
Thus the solution for you is to find all relevant occurences of `<?` and `<?=` and to replace them by `<?php` and `<?php echo` respectively.

Comment: Please don't use short open tags.

Comment: @MichaelHampton you are right, i just explain the issue to OP..

Comment: I changed it to short_open_tag=On although the default value I believe is "On"...

Comment: @Rich short open tags have defaulted OFF for many years. Their use is _not_ recommended.

Comment: Thank you; my bad. Not recommended because of conflicts with xml. Much appreciated!